# Content attribute omitted while declaring a Button in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why are those statements are equivalent in XAML?:

```
<Button>ala</Button>

<Button Content="ala"></Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a property on your control as the 'default content' of that UI control via the [ContentPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx). The `Button` control has its `Content` property marked with this attribute and hence the value of this property is used as the content.

This is a convenient shorthand in some contexts.